# How to pass hashmap from spring-boot backend to UI?

Tags: java, spring, api, enums, postman

I'm trying to pass a key-value pair from Java Spring-boot backend to the UI. I'm using enums here.I need to pass it like both `ASSIGNED` and `Assigned`. When I did log it in the backend it displays in the same that I need. But when I try them using postman the output is not the same.I have added images below how it looks

**When I did a println in the backend**
[image]

**In the postman**
[image]

**TicketResource.js**

```
/**
   * API to get status enums
   * @return list of enums
   */
  @GetMapping("/getStatusEnums")
  public HashMap getStatusEnums() {
    HashMap statusEnums = new HashMap();
    statusEnums.put(TicketStatus.UNASSIGNED,TicketStatus.UNASSIGNED.getCode());
    statusEnums.put(TicketStatus.ASSIGNED,TicketStatus.ASSIGNED.getCode());
    statusEnums.put(TicketStatus.IN_PROGRESS,TicketStatus.IN_PROGRESS.getCode());
    statusEnums.put(TicketStatus.BLOCKED,TicketStatus.BLOCKED.getCode());
    statusEnums.put(TicketStatus.RESERVED,TicketStatus.RESERVED.getCode());
    statusEnums.put(TicketStatus.ARCHIVED,TicketStatus.ARCHIVED.getCode());
    System.out.println(statusEnums);
    return statusEnums;
  }
```

StatusVO.js

```
package limark.internal.css.core.model.enums;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonValue;
import limark.internal.css.core.model.Filterable;

public enum TicketStatus implements Filterable {
    UNASSIGNED("Unassigned"),
    ASSIGNED("Assigned"),
    IN_PROGRESS("In Progress"),
    BLOCKED("Blocked"),
    RESERVED("Reserved"),
    ARCHIVED("Archived");

    private String code;

    TicketStatus(final String code) {
        this.code = code;
    }

    @JsonValue

    public String getCode() {
        return this.code;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return this.code;
    }

}
```

Is there any other way to do this?Since I'm very new to java I can't understand this much.

Comment: I think this behavior is due to the fact that you have annotated `TicketStatus#getCode ` with `@JsonValue`. Jackson will serialize your enum object using the return of such method.